# Use PHP to convert image in RGB matrix format to PNG or other displayable format

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I have some images in a DB in an RGB matrix format, a [W x H x 3] matrix.
(Side question: Is there a proper name for this format?)

Are there any tools in PHP to allow me to convert this into a displayable format such as PNG easily? My goal is to take this (byte array) image from the DB and embed it in the HTML page using base64 encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know ImageMagick can do this sort of thing, but I don't use PHP myself.

There seems to be a "method/function" called `Imagick::importImagePixels` but it may be deprecated. Details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.importimagepixels.php).

Failing that, at the command line, ImageMagick can read from a raw RGB file like this, assuming it has dimensions 500x300, and create a PNG file called `image.png`

```
convert -size 500x300 RGB:file.dat image.png
```

You may need to set `-depth 16` if your data is 16-bit. You may need to add `-endian msb` if your raw data is MSB-first endian.

You could shell out to ImageMagick from PHP and let that also create the base64 encoded image. So, for example, if you want to create a small 3 pixel Red, Green, Blue strip, you could do:

```
convert xc:red xc:green xc:blue +append png:- | base64  -i -  -o -
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAABAgMAAABmjvwnAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAADFBMVEX/AAAAgAAAAP////+OcOPKAAAAAWJLR0QDEQxM8gAAAAd0SU1FB98EEQklANW7eQgAAAAKSURBVAjXY5AAAAAaABmHBux0AAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOmNyZWF0ZQAyMDE1LTA0LTE3VDA5OjM3OjAwKzAxOjAw5tCGLgAAACV0RVh0ZGF0ZTptb2RpZnkAMjAxNS0wNC0xN1QwOTozNzowMCswMTowMJeNPpIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

So, if you could get your raw RGB data in a file called `data.bin` , you could equally do:

```
convert -size 300x200 RGB:data.bin png:- | base64  -i -  -o -
```

Another option may be to use a pixel iterator, and go through the image one pixel at a time, which is already well described in Octopus's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367141/how-to-set-color-of-a-pixel-using-imagick-for-php-imagemagick).

Answer (score 0):

I will convert a RGB array, with your [W x H x 3] matrix format, into a displayable format such as PNG, and embed the image in it, inside a HTML page using base64 encoding as you need.

However, since I haven't a DB with that kind of data, I will instead create the array from an actual image file first for the example:

```
<?php
    $filename='image.png';
    //Attempt to open 
    $img=@imagecreatefrompng($filename);
    //See if it failed
    if(!$img){
        //Create a blank image
        $width=150;
        $height=150;
        $newimg=imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
        $bgcolor=imagecolorallocate($newimg,255,255,255);
        $color=imagecolorallocate($newimg,0,0,0);
        imagefilledrectangle($newimg,0,0,$width-1,$height-1,$bgcolor);
        //Output an error message at half the height of the image
        imagestring($newimg,1,10,round($height/2),'Error loading '.$filename,$color);
    }else{

        //CONVERT IMAGE TO WxHx3 ARRAY
        $width=imagesx($img);
        $height=imagesy($img);
        //Create and array of RGB values
        $array=array();
        for($x=0;$x<$width;++$x){
            for($y=0;$y<$height;++$y){
                //Every pixel will be an array of 4 ints with the keys 'red', 'green', 'blue' and 'alpha'.
                $bytes=imagecolorat($img,$x,$y);
                $colors=imagecolorsforindex($img,$bytes);
                $array[$x][$y]=$colors;             
            }
        }       

        //CONVERT WxHx3 ARRAY TO IMAGE
        $newimg=imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
        for($x=0;$x<$width;++$x){
            for($y=0;$y<$height;++$y){
                $r=$array[$x][$y]['red'];
                $g=$array[$x][$y]['green'];
                $b=$array[$x][$y]['blue'];
                //$a=$array[$x][$y]['alpha'];
                $a=0; //0: opaque, 127: transparent
                $colors=imagecolorallocatealpha($newimg,$r,$g,$b,$a);
                imagesetpixel($newimg,$x,$y,$colors);         
            }
        }       
    }

    //Remove these comments to show the image instead of HTML
    //header('Content-Type: image/png');
    //imagepng($newimg);
    //exit();

    //Show the image inside a IMG tag
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        ob_start();
        imagepng($newimg);
        $data = ob_get_clean();
        ob_end_clean();     
        echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($data).'" />';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```